# Xcode template for Carbon app?

Tags: xcode4, macos-carbon

What would be the current way of creating a small Carbon app in Xcode 4?

I.e. we've got a bunch of small, window-less helper apps that just need building from a small number of C++ source code files but the 'old' Xcode Carbon templates seem to have vanished in Xcode 4.6

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the last version of Xcode to have Carbon templates was 2.5, and I don't know if that will run on recent OS versions.

If these apps don't have UI, why do they need to be Carbon?  Maybe they could even be command line tools?

Comment: True, anything compiling C++ with a `main()` should work! I've tried the command line tools template but the Carbon one must have set additional settings as I'm fighting with weird compiler errors..